# openGL version in macbook air?

Tags: macos, opengl

I created the following c++ code to check openGL version in my macbook air:

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutCreateWindow("GLUT");
printf("%s\n",glGetString(GL_VERSION));
}
```

When I run it, it gave me the following `2.1 INTEL-10.6.33`. Is this openGL 2.1 really in my mac? However, according to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823) openGL version that's supported by macbook air (2013) is 4.1. How do I update to openGL 4.1?

Comment: "However, according to Apple openGL version that's supported by macbook air (2013) is 4.1"...in a Core context.  Which it won't give you by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glut itself is terribly outdated and does not support OpenGL 4.1, but it has a updated and extended opensource replacement [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/). Here, one can request a specific profile:

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
... 
glutInitContextVersion (4, 1);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
```

In general, I would advice you not to use glut at all and move to a more modern way for window handling such as [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) or [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/index.php).

Comment: The GLUT version that comes standard with the Mac development tools can create core profile contexts, which includes 4.1 on machines that support it. It does show a bunch of deprecation warnings, but still works just fine if you ignore/disable them.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot "update" opengl.. OpenGl is not a software exactly. Your OpenGL version depends on your Graphics card in a way..
Al thought,
1. Does your code run?
2. Does it shows you the Console application?
3. Does it give you a runtime error?